# automatically setting a radio button in a group to selected upon returning to a page - how to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quick question regarding radio buttons, and how to set them when a user returns to a page. What I now want is to be able to show the item selected, when they RETURN to the page. There are several in the same group, so I can't use getElementByID (sadly!).

This is my HTML:

```
<input id="q1input" onblur="saveItemData(this.id)" type="radio" name="optradio" value="1 cardiovascular system">cardiovascular system

<input id="q1input" onblur="saveItemData(this.id)" type="radio" name="optradio" value="2 respiratory system">respiratory system
```

I have some code which successfully gets the checked items value:

```
var inputData = $("input:radio[name=optradio]:checked").val();
```

Then, I have the code which is called on reload:

```
var itemToCheck = document.getElementById(elementID).getAttribute("value", cleanedText);

itemToCheck.checked = true;
```

How can I target the item which was selected, then set it's checked value to true?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's never a good idea to have multiple elements with the same Id, Use class for that

Comment: Also, where do you get elementID from? You should include all relevant code

Comment: I know it's not a great idea, but I am using the same code for a whole lot of other where the id's are unique, so this is the only place they are the same - annoying:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select a specific input type having certain value using:

```
$('input[type="radio"][value="your_value"]')
```

In your case try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"][value="2"]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" value="1">One
<input type="radio" value="2">Two
```

Instead of hard code value, you can pass variable like:

```
var value = 2; 
$('input[type="radio"][value="' + value + '"]')
```

Comment: Thankyou! How can use a variable instead of the string?

Comment: @BruceHerbert `var value = 2;` `$('input[type="radio"][value="' + value + '"]')`

Comment: @Mark thanks. Bruce check the updated answer or Mark comment

Answer (score 1):

if you want to store the selected value and show that value which was selected you can use `localStorage` for that and store the value there and show it later when the page loades.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("input[name='optradio']").change(function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      window.localStorage.removeItem('optradio_value');
      window.localStorage.setItem('optradio_value',val);
   });


    var saved_value = window.localStorage.getItem('optradio_value');

    if(saved_value)
    {
      $("input[name='optradio']").attr('value',saved_value).attr('checked',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion too - I went with the other solution, as I had already started it - but yours is certainly worth considering!